# Linking tasks from Main Sites to Sub-sites

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I have a site called Academic Operations, and it has different tasks. Each task belongs to a specific "Resource Group". And for each "Resource Group", I have different sub-sites like Marketing, Advising etc. 
What I want is that when i make changes to my main site i.e Academic Operations, I want the changes to reflect in sub-sites like Marketing, Advising etc. 
Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: Can somebody please help regarding the above question? If you have any doubts in question, please let me know.

Comment: I can elaborate more on the question. On my main site: main.aspx I have a main task.  What I really want to happen is that if a task has lets say Marketing as a target group that task will be copied to the marketing subsite: marketing.aspx .  or if I have something coded for Advising I would want that to go to the Advising site. 
Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

what kind of changes do you mean? 
If you mean sharing documents between the sites, it is generally not possible. You can add links, etc., but you should regard the sites as separate.
If you mean layout - have you tried editing the master page? You can edit it using Sharepoint Designer - it's free software.

Comment: Change as in , when I add some task in my Main Site(Academic Operations), it should be automatically updated in sub-sites(Marketing, Advising etc).